# Why is Heroku failing to understand routes but my local does?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, controller, routes

My routes :

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :manage_users do
```

And then I can have my controller in /controllers as :

```
class ManageUsersController < ApplicationController
```

Which works fine. I go to `/admin/manage_users` and I get my index.

But on Heroku I get :

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Admin::ManageUsersController):
```

Why? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the controller without renaming it to :

```
controllers/admin/
```

And my views as well. Works locally and on Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

Restart your development server and you will most likely see the same error.

When you use a namespace, Rails expects your controller to be `Admin::ManageUsersController`. See the Rails Routing guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing

Comment: But it does on my local, so there's no way for it work both on Heroku and on my Local.